# Testing Google Cloud PubSub push endpoints locally

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Trying to figure out the best way to test PubSub push endpoints locally. We tried with ngrok.io, but you must own the domain in order to whitelist (the tool for doing so is also broken… resulting in an infinite redirect loop). We also tried emulating PubSub locally. I am able to publish and pull, but I cannot get the push subscriptions working. We are using a local Flask webserver like so:

```
@app.route('/_ah/push-handlers/events', methods=['POST'])
def handle_message():
    print request.json
    return jsonify({'ok': 1}), 200
```

The following produces no result:

```
client = pubsub.Client()
topic = client('events')
topic.create()
subscription = topic.subscription('test_push', push_endpoint='http://localhost:5000/_ah/push-handlers/events')
subscription.create()
topic.publish('{"test": 123}')
```

It does yell at us when we attempt to create a subscription to an HTTP endpoint (whereas live PubSub will if you do not use HTTPS). Perhaps this is by design? Pull works just fine… Any ideas on how to best develop PubSub push endpoints locally?

Comment: We're facing a similar issue with the Ruby client... Did you get this resolved? I can add w/o issue, just nothing sent.

Comment: Actually, for anyone else having issues with this and the ruby client. Update gcloud and do a bundle update. Things are better.

Comment: do know how can i use pubsub client with psq? I am getting credentials error

Comment: Any chance you got this resolved? I wanted to test it as well by creating a local NodeJs endpoint and expose it on the web with ngrok

Answer (score 4):

Following the [latest PubSub library documentation at the time of writing](https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/1.3.1/index.html), the following example creates a subscription with a push configuration.

#### Requirements

I have tested with the following requirements :

- Google Cloud SDK 285.0.1 (for PubSub local emulator)
- Python 3.8.1
- Python packages (`requirements.txt`) :

```
flask==1.1.1
google-cloud-pubsub==1.3.1
```

#### Run PubSub emulator locally

```sh
export PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=fake-project
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=$PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID
```

By default, PubSub emulator starts on port 8085.
Project argument can be anything and does not matter.

#### Flask server

Considering the following `server.py` :

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/_ah/push-handlers/events', methods=['POST'])
def handle_message():
    print(request.json)
    return jsonify({'ok': 1}), 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

Run the server (starts on port 5000) :

```sh
python server.py
```

#### PubSub example

Considering the following `pubsub.py` :

```py
import sys

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    project_id = sys.argv[1]

    # 1. create topic (events)
    publisher_client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher_client.topic_path(project_id, "events")
    publisher_client.create_topic(topic_path)

    # 2. create subscription (test_push with push_config)
    subscriber_client = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber_client.subscription_path(
        project_id, "test_push"
    )
    subscriber_client.create_subscription(
        subscription_path,
        topic_path,
        push_config={
          'push_endpoint': 'http://localhost:5000/_ah/push-handlers/events'
        }
    )

    # 3. publish a test message
    publisher_client.publish(
        topic_path,
        data='{"test": 123}'.encode("utf-8")
    )
```

Finally, run this script :

```sh
PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8085 \
PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID=fake-project \
python pubsub.py $PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID
```

#### Results

Then, you can see the results in Flask server's log :

```
{'subscription': 'projects/fake-project/subscriptions/test_push', 'message': {'data': 'eyJ0ZXN0IjogMTIzfQ==', 'messageId': '1', 'attributes': {}}}
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Mar/2020 12:11:00] "POST /_ah/push-handlers/events HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Note that you can retrieve the message sent, encoded here in base64 (`message.data`) :

```sh
$ echo "eyJ0ZXN0IjogMTIzfQ==" | base64 -d
{"test": 123}
```

Of course, you can also do the decoding in Python.

Comment: This approach works like a charm and was wondering what'd be the best way to implement this in a CI pipline. The only thing that I've thought of is to set everything up with `docker-compose` and run tests in a containerized fashion. Is there anything I might be overlooking?

Comment: @anddt if your app is containerized, then `docker-compose` is a good idea to orchestrate both emulator and your app I think !

Answer (score 0):

This could be a known bug (fix forthcoming) in the emulator where push endpoints created along with the subscription don't work. The bug only affects the initial push config; modifying the push config for an existing subscription should work. Can you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I failed to get PubSub emulator to work on my local env (fails with various java exceptions). I didn't even get to try various features like push with auth, etc. So I end up using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose my local dev server and used the public https URL from ngrok in PubSub subscription.

I had no issue with whitelisting and redirects like described in the Q.
So might be helpful for anyone else.